# Error from SQL query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, oracle11g

Currently I'm working on cleaning up some code on the backend of an application I'm contracted for maintenance to.  I ran across a method where a call is being made to the DB via Oracle Data Reader.  After examining the SQL, I realized it was not necessary to make the call to open up Oracle Data Reader seeing how the object being loaded up was already within the Context of our Entity Framework.  I changed the code to follow use of the Entity Model instead.  Below are the changes I made.

Original code

```
var POCs = new List<TBLPOC>();

Context.Database.Connection.Open();
var cmd = (OracleCommand)Context.Database.Connection.CreateCommand();
OracleDataReader reader;
var SQL = string.Empty;
if (IsAssociate == 0)
    SQL = @"SELECT tblPOC.cntPOC,INITCAP(strLastName),INITCAP(strFirstName)
            FROM tblPOC,tblParcelToPOC
            WHERE tblParcelToPOC.cntPOC = tblPOC.cntPOC AND
              tblParcelToPOC.cntAsOf = 0 AND
              tblParcelToPOC.cntParcel  = " + cntParcel + " ORDER BY INITCAP(strLastName)";
else
    SQL = @"SELECT cntPOC,INITCAP(strLastName),INITCAP(strFirstName)
            FROM tblPOC 
            WHERE tblPOC.cntPOC NOT IN ( SELECT cntPOC
                                         FROM tblParcelToPOC
                                         WHERE cntParcel = " + cntParcel + @"
                                           AND cntAsOf = 0 )
               AND tblPOC.ysnActive = 1 ORDER BY INITCAP(strLastName)";
cmd.CommandText = SQL;
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
using (reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        POCs.Add(new TBLPOC { CNTPOC = (decimal)reader[0],
                              STRLASTNAME = reader[1].ToString(),
                              STRFIRSTNAME = reader[2].ToString() });
    }
}
Context.Database.Connection.Close();
return POCs;
```

Replacement code

```
var sql = string.Empty;
if (IsAssociate == 0)
    sql = string.Format(@"SELECT tblPOC.cntPOC,INITCAP(strLastName),INITCAP(strFirstName)
                          FROM tblPOC,tblParcelToPOC
                          WHERE tblParcelToPOC.cntPOC = tblPOC.cntPOC
                              AND tblParcelToPOC.cntAsOf = 0
                              AND tblParcelToPOC.cntParcel = {0}
                          ORDER BY INITCAP(strLastName)",
                          cntParcel);
else
    sql = string.Format(@"SELECT cntPOC,INITCAP(strLastName), INITCAP(strFirstName)
                          FROM tblPOC 
                          WHERE tblPOC.cntPOC NOT IN (SELECT cntPOC
                                                      FROM tblParcelToPOC
                                                      WHERE cntParcel = {0}
                                                        AND cntAsOf = 0)
                              AND tblPOC.ysnActive = 1
                          ORDER BY INITCAP(strLastName)",
                          cntParcel);

return Context.Database.SqlQuery<TBLPOC>(sql, "0").ToList<TBLPOC>();
```

The issue I'm having right now is when the replacement code is executed, I get the following error:

**The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'TBLPOC'.  A member of the type 'CNTPOCORGANIZATION', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.**

The field cntPOCOrganization does exist within tblPOC, as well as within the TBLPOC Entity.  cntPOCOrganization is a nullable decimal (don't ask why decimal, I myself don't get why the previous contractors used decimals versus ints for identifiers...).  However, in the past code and the newer code, there is no need to fill that field.  I'm confused on why it is errors out on that particular field.

If anyone has any insight, I would truly appreciate it.  Thanks.

EDIT:  So after thinking on it a bit more and doing some research, I think I know what the issue is.  In the Entity Model for TBLPOC, the cntPOCOrganization field is null, however, there is an object tied to this Entity Model called TBLPOCORGANIZATION.  I'm pondering if it's trying to fill it.  It too has cntPOCOrganization within itself and I'm guessing that maybe it is trying to fill itself and is what is causing the issue.

That maybe possibly why the previous contractor wrote the Oracle Command versus run it through the Entity Framework.  I'm going to revert back for time being (on a deadline and really don't want to play too long with it).  Thanks!

Comment: It sounds to me like the reader does not have all the fields the Framework needs to fill out the objects.

Comment: Like I mentioned before, I think the issue is the child Entities associated with this Entity.  The reader notes them and because there are non-nulls in the child objects, an error gets thrown.  It could be also that the object is missing almost all of it's fields also based on the query (query only pulls three fields, when in reality there are more like 10-15 fields altogether).

Comment: Yes, I think you are on the right track. You are asking EF to map the results of the query for you so it's expecting the reader to have everything. I am curious, is the field "cntPOCOrganization" an object or a set? It's its an object then it must be a 1 to 1 relationship on the database.

Comment: It's actually a Nullable Decimal field in the Model, and a Nullable Number in the DB.  An object was added to the Model to a child class which has it's own cntPOCOrganization, which is not Nullable at that point.  My only guess is like I mentioned before, when I call out for the parent Entity, it is trying to build the child Entity also, hence why it breaks everything.

Answer (score 0):

This error is issued when your EF entity model does not match the query result. If you post your entity model you are trying to fetch this in, the SQL can be fixed. In general you need to use:

```
sql = string.Format(@"SELECT tblPOC.cntPOC AS <your_EF_model_property_name_here>,INITCAP(strLastName) AS <your_EF_model_property_name_here>,INITCAP(strFirstName) AS <your_EF_model_property_name_here>
                      FROM tblPOC,tblParcelToPOC
                      WHERE tblParcelToPOC.cntPOC = tblPOC.cntPOC
                          AND tblParcelToPOC.cntAsOf = 0
                          AND tblParcelToPOC.cntParcel = {0}
                      ORDER BY INITCAP(strLastName)",
                      cntParcel);
```

Comment: I did correct the names after I posted because I thought the same thing.  However, I still get the same error.